# ctrl-c ctrl-v stopped working in visual studio 2010 and 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Can't figure out what happened and not addons were installed lately.
Does anyone have an idea what could cause it?

Comment: What about other programs, other than visual studio?

Comment: [Have you tried turning it off and on again?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it is isolated to Visual Studio go to Tools--> Options --> Keyboard and verify that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> are still bound to `Edit.Copy` and `Edit.Paste` respectively.

Comment: For me it helped when I reset the shortcuts back to default.

Comment: Still relevant for vs 2015

Answer (score 4):

Go to visual studio

In Tools > Options > Keyboard

set mapping scheme dropdonw to Default and click on Reset button.

Restart Visual studio at once.

Your problem may resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2022. Go to Tools > Options > Keyboard and set "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme:" to (Default) and click on reset. Then restart visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I found that key sequence is override by VIM extension in editor. Disable VIM Extension if you don't need it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).